# Using setTimeout to print a string char by char

Tags: javascript, string, settimeout

I'm trying to do something very simple, but it's not working and I can't figure out why not. I am trying to write some text to a div such that the text appears one character at a time; sort of like that scene in the matrix.

```
var message = document.getElementById("message");
  function writeMessage(string) {
    message.innerHTML = string.charAt(0);
    for (var i = 1; i < string.length; i++) {
      window.setTimeout(function() {message.innerHTML+=string.charAt(i);},1000);
    }
  }
  writeMessage("Hello world");
```

To see my code's inaction in action, see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ddWs3/). As you can tell, it displays only the first character, as if setTimeout is not executing the function at all.

Comment: setTimeout will call the insde function in 1 second. It won't freeze the program and the loop will continue. So you basically transfer the whole string print 1 second later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function that you pass to `setTimeout` is actually executed *after* your loop completes the `i` variable will equal `string.length` when it executes. You could try to solve this by storing `i` to a temporary variable, or by using an [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression). However, all the function instances you've registered with `setTimeout` will end up executing at approximately the same time, so you won't see any animation.

Perhaps try using `setInterval`, like this:

```
function writeMessage(string) {
    var i = 0, intervalId;
    intervalId = window.setInterval(function() {
        message.innerHTML += string.charAt(i++);
        if (i > string.length) 
            window.clearInterval(intervalId);
    }, 100); 
}

writeMessage("Hello world");
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/pQrBL/)

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work perfectly. Can you offer any insight as to why my approach didn't work?

Comment: @user3264259 I've included some explanation of the issues in the first part of my answer. What specific concerns did you have?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I understand what's happening now.

Comment: Quick followup question. Is there an easy way to force javascript to wait to execute writeMessage until after the current message has been completed? When writeMessage is called twice in quick succession, it writes both messages at once resulting in jumbled and unreadable text. I tried fixing this with an isDone boolean variable to no avail.

Comment: @user3264259 Well, the easiest solution would be to just call `writeMessage("msg1 msg2")`, but you could also redesign it to take an array of strings and loop through each string in succession. However, the most general solution would be to use [promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/) of some sort.

Comment: Thanks again! I love me a general solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
function writeMessage(text) {
    message.innerHTML = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(function (char) {
            return function () { message.innerHTML += char; };
        }(text[i]), i * 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Any idea how to prevent [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ddWs3/1/) from happening when writeMessage is called multiple times? I want it to wait until it's done with the first message before it begins writing the second.

Comment: You would have to store a lock variable and queue the subsequent messages. That would make the code a little more complex. Perhaps creating an object to handle all this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive function, ans slice each character by incrementing the index, and I call the function in the setTimeout, so each character prints on the screen, I added a condition to stop when all characters are read

```
function writeText(text) {
    textEl.innerText = text.slice(0, idx);

    idx++;

    if (idx > text.length) {
        return text;
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
        writeText(text);
    }, 500);
}
```